# X-Ray scraping and present json in the server browser

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, x-ray

I'm using [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) to scrape a website, however i can't seem to show the correct JSON output in the browser. It works fine, when i write a new json doc like `write('result.json')` however now when i try to send it to the browser. i'm at the moment using express as the web framework.

This below creates a new result.json file and show the correct json output (urls on dribbble.com). However is not showing it in the browser as i want?

```
app.get('/api/standings', function(req, res, next){


    x('http://www.dribbble.com', 'a', [{
    url: '@href',
    }]).write()
'results.json'


});
```

**what i've tried**

```
app.get('/api/standings', function(req, res, next){

    res.send(x('http://www.dribbble.com', 'a', [{
        url: '@href',
    }]).write());



});
```

**weird wrong output**

```
{
  "_readableState": {
    "objectMode": false,
    "highWaterMark": 16384,
    "buffer": [

    ],
    "length": 0,
    "pipes": null,
    "pipesCount": 0,
    "flowing": null,
    "ended": false,
    "endEmitted": false,
    "reading": false,
    "sync": true,
    "needReadable": false,
    "emittedReadable": false,
    "readableListening": false,
    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
    "ranOut": false,
    "awaitDrain": 0,
    "readingMore": false,
    "decoder": null,
    "encoding": null
  },
  "readable": true,
  "domain": null,
  "_events": {

  },
  "_eventsCount": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .write will return you a [enstore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enstore) stream. You have pipe it to your node GET response to make it work.

```
app.get('/api/standings', function(req, res, next){

    x('http://www.dribbble.com', 'a', [{
    url: '@href',
    }]).write().pipe(res);

});
```